# Lazy loading module not found error in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

I have copied my existing Angular Project src and package.json file and created new angular project and replaced with my backup src and package.json files.

After that i run `npm install`. when i try to run the project by `ng serve` command i am getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/src/app/ads1/ads1.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/$$_lazy_route_resource'
ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/src/app/ads2/ads2.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/$$_lazy_route_resource'
ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/src/app/ads3/ads3.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/$$_lazy_route_resource'
ERROR in ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Desktop/Angular/matrix/src/app/banner/banner.module.ngfactory.js' in '/Users/Desktop/A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah found the issues its an angular version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add paths to your lazy loaded modules to "files" in tsconig.aot.json:

```
...
"files" [
   ...
   "./ads1/ads1.module.ts",
   etc
   ...
],
```